# Wrapping two ScrollViews into a LinearLayout

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-linearlayout, android-scrollview

I am struggling to find a solution for one of the Android Studio (Kotlin) class problems by Google: how to add another image that scrolls down with the first ScrollView. I created a LinearLayout that has two ScrollViews within it. The first ScrollView has a large amount of text which scrolls down perfectly. However, in the second ScrollView, for the image above the text, it does not scroll down with the text.

Here is a view of the Design element of the activity_main (the green bar below the star is ImageView1 which is in the second ScrollView):
[image]

Here is the code for the ScrollViews in my activity_main:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bio_scroll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/button_onoff_indicator_on" />
    </ScrollView>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bio_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="463dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bio_text"
            style="@style/NameStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
            android:text="@string/bio" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Some guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using two `ScrollView`?

Comment: The task is to place another image within the LinearLayout and make it scrollable with the other ScrollView.

Comment: Then why not a single `ScrollView`? If you want to scroll the image with the text, you can do it with a single ScrollView. Or do you want to scroll the image corresponding to the scrolling of text? but in this case where will you scroll the image? I still don't get the reason of using two separate ScrollViews.

Comment: You cannot put two Views in one ScrollView.

Comment: I am not sure whether this problem occurs only for the Kotlin version of Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I told you to use only one `ScrollView` is that you don't need two. You can use any number of views in a `Scrollview`, just make sure the child of `ScrollView` is a `Layout`. You can use any layout and then put whatever you have in that layout. That's how `ScrollView` is used.

As the [official docs  of `ScrollView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView) state :

> Scroll view may have only one direct child placed within it.
> To add multiple views within the scroll view, make the direct child
> you add a view group, for example LinearLayout, and place additional
> views within that LinearLayout.

So, change your code as :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/bio_scroll2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/button_onoff_indicator_on" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/bio_text"
                style="@style/NameStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.2"
                android:text="@string/bio" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Furthermore, You can remove the root `LinearLayout` if you don't want to add any other view in it and that will make the `ScrollView` the root layout.

Also, the `height` as `match_parent` doesn't work in `ScrollView` and it works only as `wrap_content` or any fix size so if you want to make it take the full height of its parent, you've to use `android:fillViewport="true"` in `ScrollView's` tag and height of its parent should be `match_parent`.